# Text align vertical doesn't work in tags

Tags: android

I have a problem about vertical alignment. My codes like below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<co.hairmod.android.post.create.TokenLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/catalog_tag_textview_cornered"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:paddingLeft="23dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="deneme"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_circle"
        android:textColor="@color/main_photo_orange_circle_color"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:text="X"/>

</RelativeLayout>


</co.hairmod.android.post.create.TokenLayout>
```

But my appearance is like this;

[image]

It is not exactly vertical align. I have tried every way, paddings, margins. But It haven't worked still.

Answer (score 0):

Add android:layout_centerVertical="true" attribute to TextView